# Error running setup:upgrade : Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.inventory_low_stock_notification_configuration' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, database, setup-upgrade

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 and i disabled all Magento 2 inventory extensions, when running php bin/magento setup:upgrade, i encountered this error:

```
Schema creation/updates:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.inventory_low_stock_notification_configuration' doesn't exist, query was: SHOW CREATE TABLE inventory_low_stock_notification_configuration
```

i already ran the following command, but still got the same error:

```
rm -rf var/cache/
rm -rf var/page_cache/
rm -rf generated/code/
rm -rf generated/metadata/
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to run this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory_low_stock_notification_configuration` (
  `source_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `notify_stock_qty` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`source_code`,`sku`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```